# Android camera image to a custom folder is blank

Tags: android, camera, android-gallery

Greetings i'm trying to develop an activity in my app where the user captures an image using the camera and save it to a custom folder in my gallery 
here is the code i'm using

```
 public class CameraFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "testcma";
    private static final int REQUEST_DATE = 0;
    private static final int REQUEST_PHOTO = 1;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private View mProgressContainer;
    OutputStream outStream = null;

    String fileName;
    private Camera.ShutterCallback mShutterCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {
            // Display the progress indicator
            mProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };
    private Camera.PictureCallback mJpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            // Create a filename
            fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
            // Save the jpeg data to disk
            FileOutputStream os = null;
            boolean success = true;
            try {
                if (isDir()) {

                }
                /*
                 * os = getActivity().openFileOutput(fileName,
                 * Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                 */// os.write(data);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error writing to file " + fileName, e);
                success = false;
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (os != null)
                        os.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error closing file " + fileName, e);
                    success = false;
                }
            }
            if (success) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_PHOTO_FILENAME, fileName);
                getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);

            } else {
                getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
            }
            getActivity().finish();
            getActivity().finish();
        }

        private boolean isDir() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // File file = createImageFile();

                final String appDirectoryName = "XYZ";
                final File imageRoot = new File(
                        Environment
                                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                        appDirectoryName);
                boolean x = imageRoot.mkdirs();
                x = imageRoot.isDirectory();

                OutputStream fOut = null;
                File imagePath = new File(imageRoot.getAbsolutePath());
                File file = new File(imagePath, "GE_" + fileName); // File = new
                                                                    // File(fileName);

                try {
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {

                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, "title");
                values.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "descriptoin");
                values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
                values.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID, file.toString()
                        .toLowerCase(Locale.US).hashCode());
                values.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, file
                        .getName().toLowerCase(Locale.US));
                values.put("_data", file.getAbsolutePath());

                ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
                cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                // final File image = new File(imageRoot,fileName );

            return false;

        }
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pin_camera, container,
                false);

        mProgressContainer = view
                .findViewById(R.id.pin_camera_progressContainer);
        mProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ImageButton takePicButton = (ImageButton) view
                .findViewById(R.id.camera_button);
        takePicButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (mCamera != null) {
                    mCamera.takePicture(mShutterCallback, null, mJpegCallback);
                }
            }
        });
        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.pin_camera_surfaceView);
        SurfaceHolder holder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                // Tell the camera to use this surface as its preview area
                try {
                    if (mCamera != null) {
                        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                    }
                } catch (IOException exception) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error setting up preview display", exception);
                }
            }

            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                // We can no longer display on this surface, so stop the
                // preview.
                if (mCamera != null) {
                    mCamera.stopPreview();
                }
            }

            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w,
                    int h) {
                if (mCamera == null)
                    return;
                // The surface has changed size; update the camera preview size
                Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                Size s = getBestSupportedSize(
                        parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes(), w, h); // To be
                                                                        // reset
                                                                        // in
                                                                        // the
                                                                        // next
                                                                        // section
                parameters.setPreviewSize(s.width, s.height);
                s = getBestSupportedSize(parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes(),
                        w, h);
                parameters.setPictureSize(s.width, s.height);
                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                try {
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not start preview", e);
                    mCamera.release();
                    mCamera = null;
                }
            }
        });
        //
        return view;
    }

    @TargetApi(20)
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            mCamera = Camera.open(0);
        } else {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    private Size getBestSupportedSize(List<Size> sizes, int width, int height) {
        Size bestSize = sizes.get(0);
        int largestArea = bestSize.width * bestSize.height;
        for (Size s : sizes) {
            int area = s.width * s.height;
            if (area > largestArea) {
                bestSize = s;
                largestArea = area;
            }
        }
        return bestSize;
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis() + "";
        fileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        String storageDir = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                + "/XYZ";
        File dir = new File(storageDir);
        dir.mkdir();

        File image = new File(storageDir + "/" + fileName + ".jpg");

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        fileName = image.getAbsolutePath();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, "title");
        values.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "descriptoin");
        values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID,
                image.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.US).hashCode());
        values.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, image.getName()
                .toLowerCase(Locale.US));
        values.put("_data", image.getAbsolutePath());

        ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

        Log.i(TAG, "photo path = " + fileName);
        return image;
    }

}
```

it captures the image and creates the folder and image file in it but the image is blank just flat black, can you help me with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually saving the `jpeg` buffer data onto the file,
you are creating the directories inside `isDir` and also creating a file there with an extension `jpg` with `fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);` but you are not saving the actually image contents to it

**EDIT** here is how you can save the data to the file

```
 String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";

 File directory = new File(Environment
    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "XYZ");

   // Save the jpeg data to disk
   boolean success = true;
   try {
     if (!directory.isDirectory() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
         throw new IOException("unable to make directories for path " + directory);
     }

     File file = new File(directory, "GE_" + fileName);
     FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

     fOut.write(data);
     fOut.close();
     MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(CameraActivity.this, new String[] {file.getAbsolutePath()},
                                new String[]{"image/jpg"}, null);
   } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: Where is data defined?